# Batch file closing abruptly after running Rselenium

Tags: batch-file, rselenium

I have a R script that I'm trying to run through a batch file. The job is supposed to start a Rselenium server, **scrape** some information from a website and close the connection.

If I run the script in R-studio there's no problem, everything goes well. However, every time I try to run it through a Batch, It starts well, but after navigating for around 10 seconds, the CMD closes abruptly, stopping the script but leaving the Rselenium server opened.

Would you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I tried different ways but nothing seems to work.

My Batch looks something like this:

```
@echo on && "C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\Desktop\myrscript.R" && Pause && @echo on && @echo off
```

It also looks like some process is still running in the background, because it doesn't allow me to modify the script, nor opening a new Rselenium instance.

thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't you be executing it with `rscript.exe`?

Comment: Not understanding why you coded your script like that either.  Why do you need the conditional execution after every single command?

Comment: Regardless of the misunderstanding between `&` and `&&`, you don't need any of those `echo` commands at all, _unless your `cmd.exe` instance is being run with `echo`ing off (either via its `/Q` option or an AutoRun command when the `/D` option is omitted), and in that case you'd only need the first one._ Also there is no such command as `@echo`, the command is just `echo`, although if you were using an `on` instruction at the beginning, and an unnecessary `off` one at the end, I'd advise that both are prepended with `@`.

Comment: To show you what I'd have expected to see, `@"C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\myrscript.R" & Pause`, or `@"C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\RScript.exe" "C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\myrscript.R" & Pause`. Turning echo on will only show you the command being run, nothing else. If that is what you wanted, then use, `@Echo On & "C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\myrscript.R" & @Echo Off & Pause`, or `@Echo On & "C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\RScript.exe" "C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\myrscript.R" & @Echo Off & Pause`.

Comment: If your command is closing abruptly, i.e. before you get to see a `Press any key to continue . . .` type message _(English version provided)_, then the issue is likely to be with your R script not the batch file, and for help with that we'd need to see its content.

Comment: Compo, ```@Echo On & "C:\Users\Documents\R\R-3.6.1\bin\RScript.exe" "C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\myrscript.R" & @Echo Off & Pause``` worked! . I think Rscript.exe instead of R.exe (together with the mistakes I've done) were the reason why it was aborting everything like that.
Thanks for your support. I'm only starting with Batch files and cmd.